# DEPRECATION: Uninstalling a distutils installed project (pyOpenSSL) has been deprecated error while installing simple_salesforce python library

Tags: integration, python

I am trying to install the python library for salesforce.
I am trying on mac in the terminal using command `sudo pip install simple_salesforce`

but I get an error while installing this. The error:

> DEPRECATION: Uninstalling a distutils installed project (pyOpenSSL)
>   has been deprecated and will be removed in a future version. This is
>   due to the fact that uninstalling a distutils project will only
>   partially uninstall the project.
>       Uninstalling pyOpenSSL-0.13.1: Exception: Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py",
>   line 215, in main
>       status = self.run(options, args)   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py",
>   line 342, in run
>       prefix=options.prefix_path,   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_set.py",
>   line 778, in install
>       requirement.uninstall(auto_confirm=True)   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py",
>   line 754, in uninstall
>       paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_uninstall.py",
>   line 115, in remove
>       renames(path, new_path)   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/utils/**init**.py",
>   line 267, in renames
>       shutil.move(old, new)   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py",
>   line 302, in move
>       copy2(src, real_dst)   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py",
>   line 131, in copy2
>       copystat(src, dst)   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py",
>   line 103, in copystat
>       os.chflags(dst, st.st_flags) OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted:
>   '/tmp/pip-_GSJZj-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pyOpenSSL-0.13.1-py2.7.egg-info'

Any help on how can I install the simple salesforce library from the terminal.

I have python version installed: Python 2.7.10
and the postgre is also installed up and running fine.

Answer (score 1):

ok..I was able to find out the answer for this question.
We can only install this python library for salesforce into a virtual environment `$ pip install virtualenv` .
First we will have to create a virtual environment and then need to activate this by using `source bin/activate` command.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can also just ignore it.

```
sudo pip install simple_salesforce --ignore-installed pyOpenSSL
```